# Why is the crawler method not called in the spider?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Why is the "parse_product" method not called in my code:

```
import scrapy
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from staff_crawlers.items import Persona
from datetime import date
import time


class SiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'site.com'
    driver = uc.Chrome(version_main=97)

    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver.get('https://some.site.com/login/')
        time.sleep(5)

        login = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email_field')
        login.send_keys('myLogin')
        password = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password_field')
        password.send_keys('myPassword')
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.parse_page('https://some.site.com/products/')

    def parse_page(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        html = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        for prod in html.css('a.resume-card__title-link::attr("href")').getall():
            url = 'https://some.site.com/products/' + prod
            self.parse_product(url)

        next_page = html.css('a[rel="next"]::attr("href")').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            self.parse_page('https://some.site.com/products/' + next_page)

    def parse_product(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        ...
```

among other things, I get an error:

```
start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

at the same time, the spider reaches the for loop (for prod in html.css('a.resume-card__title-link::attr("href")').getall()), gets all the links to the products, and then there is pagination, that is, after authorization of the transition to the desired page with products, only pagination occurs, product cards are not opened...
what's wrong?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you use scrapy in wrong way - you run directly `self.parse_page()` but Scrapy doesn't work this way. You have to `yield` request with URL and `callback=parse_page` and it will send it to `engine` which will download page and later send this page to `parse_page`. But you sends url directly to `parse_page` and it will not work.

Comment: function `start_requests` should use `yield` to generate list with requests but your `start_requests` runs directly `self.parse_page()` and later it returns only `None` -and this makes problem. Scrapy has more complex structure then only this class - see image in documentation: [Architecture overview](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)

Comment: you should write it without `scrapy` because at this moment you don't use its functions,  so `scrapy` is totaly useless for you.

Comment: or you would have to create Middleware similar to [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/) which uses standard ("detectable") `selenium`